# Rspec receive post from tested application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I am testing a running application using rspec/capybara. I have a route I want to test that is supposed to talk to a secondary service via a provided url.

Since the tests don't encapsulate the application, they just talk to it, I cant use the normal methods of stubbing out api calls, to make sure its calling the service properly.

What I would like is to be able to give the route a url, then have rspec receive a post back from the application. Is there a way to do this?

To be clear, I do NOT want rspec to mock/stub the request, because this isn't running as a wrapper to the application.

Comment: Can you show how you app interacts with the secondary service? "they just talk to it" is really vague. I don't know what you mean with "this isn't running as a wrapper to the application". Please show some code and be more precise on the description.

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose the secondary service response is exposed somehow back to you.

So hitting `https://not-my-service.com?secondary-service=http://service-i-control.com` results in something that contains the response (partial or complete) from `http://service-i-control.com`.

If this service is up & running in production your `secondary-service` must also be something exposed to the internet, you can consider using something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose a local Rack application your testing environment is spinning up that returns a specific response.

If you don't mind using external services you could also consider using [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/) for example: `https://not-my-service.com?secondary-service=https://httpbin.org/ip` you will return a 200 OK with the IP of the origin that hit the server. So you could match that IP to `https://not-my-service.com`.

If you don't get any information besides the fact that it calls the `secondary-service` then I would suggest as part of the spec:

1. Spin up a rack application and expose it to the internet.
2. Hit the service passing your local application as parameter.
3. Wait until you get the request your are expecting, then stop the application and the test has succeeded.
4. **Or** it times out (say 30 seconds) and your test has failed (service was never called).